# Using itertools with a generator class

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a class that generates words from a file the program reads in. I'm stuck with the `__iter__` and `next` methods. My idea is to obviously read in the file in `__init__` but I'm confused about how to iterate over it because I know `itertools` will be doing something similar. Any advice?

Currently I have this code.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.words = []
    self.n = 0
    with open('words.txt') as f:
        text = f.read()
    for x in text.split():
        if len(x) > 2 and x[0].islower():
            self.words.append(x)

def __iter__(self):
    return self


def next(self):
    if(self.n == 0):
        self.n = self.n + 1
        return self.words[0]
    else:
        self.n = self.n + 1
        return self.words[self.n-1]
```

This is how the code should run.

```
>>> mw = MerriamWebster()
>>> [w for w in itertools.islice(mw, 5)]
['aal', 'aalii', 'aam', 'aardvark', 'aardwolf']
```

Comment: `next` doesn't take an argument.  Your class will have to keep track of the current file location/word index itself.

Comment: So I added an n to keep track of the location and thought that would be the answer. But now it just keeps returning the same word?

Comment: It might be easier to read in the entire file as a string (`text = f.read()`) and then iterate with `for x in text.split()` to split the string into space-separated words. There's a little issue of punctuation and such, but having `words` contain near-words is progress.

Comment: you should be incrementing `n` in `next`, not `__iter__`

Comment: Figured it out! Python is the best :)

Comment: @recurrenceprobs: so either accept one of these answers right now, or post your  own answer and accept that; either way upvote everyone who helped you, and close the question right now before more of us waste time on this. Doing anything else is being a help vampire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `__iter__` method in this case needs to return an object that keeps track of it's position.

If `__iter__` returns `self`, you could track this position in an instance variable, but it's mixing two responsibilities, and means you can't have two (or more) independent iterators over your object. It can make sense in some cases though.

It looks like you really just want a generator here

```
def MerriamWebster(fname='words.txt'):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for x in f:
            if len(x) >= 2:
                yield x
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want iteration over your object to be only over the words member, why not do:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.words)
```

And delegate the index tracking to the list iterator.